# comparing values of multiple facts with each other in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
 workers(name(nasrin,sultana),eng,address(dhanmondi,city1,bangladesh),40).
 workers(name(kabita,chy),doctor,address(motijheel,city1,bangladesh),35).
 workers(name(nasima,akter),lecturer,address(agrabad,city2,bangladesh),30).
 workers(name(afroja,sultana),doctor,address(gec,city2,bangladesh),45).
 samecity(F,L):-
 workers(name(_,_),_,address(_,A,_),_),         
 workers(name(F,L),_,address(_,A,_),_).
```

my query is : Who lives in the same city?i have written a rule knowing that it ain't going to work for this query but couldn't make any accurate rule for the query.

Comment: The city for a given person comes from `workers(Name, _, address(_, City, _), _).` If you want the same city for two different names, use the same variable. Two names are in the same city if this query is true for two different names. You can also apply a condition that both names are necessarily different: `dif(Name1, Name2)`.

Comment: `samecity(F, L)` has a single first and single last name for arguments. When the query succeeds, what does a single solution (single first and last name) mean? What kind of results do you want?

Comment: Thank you for your response.In this case i am not supposed to know how many of them reside in city1,city2.The answer for this query should be the names of the workers who have a common city.All of the names should be printed(with or without addition information of the city name which is common between them)for these given facts .How am i supposed to do that with variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a starting process.

Since you may have multiple solutions to "all the names that live in the same city" (since this may be true for multiple cities), then I'd suggest writing a predicate of the following form:

```
same_city(City, NameList).
```

Now you can focus on writing that predicate since the arguments consist of a single City and will provide a list of one or more names:

```
same_city(City, NameList) :-
    findall(Name, workers(...), NameList)).
```

I'll leave it to you to fill in the `...`.

Now this will give you solutions that even have a single name in a given city. If you only want this to succeed for cities with at least two names, you need to specify that condition:

```
at_least_two_same_city(City, NameList) :-
    findall(Name, workers(...), NameList)),
    length(NameList, NumberOfNames),
    NumberOfNames > 1.
```

Another way to ensure a list of length > 1 is to use the form `[_,_|_]` for the list which makes for a tidier solution:

```
at_least_two_same_city(City, NameList) :-
    NameList = [_,_|_],   % We only want lists with at least 2 members
    findall(Name, workers(...), NameList)).
```

Finally, if you want all of the solutions to this predicate, you could use `findall/3` again on that predicate:

```
findall(City-NameList, at_least_two_same_city(City, NameList), AllMultipleNameCitiesAndNames).
```

Comment: I appreciate what you did. I will try this one. Thanks a lot Sir

Comment: @Neela If I answered your question satisfactorily, please don't forget to check accept. :)